# How to manipulate date time using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to manipulate date which come from the api.

When I use: `console.log(dataAPI.dateStation)`

I see `2023-01-24T06:00:00.000Z`

Is there way to change the date time in this format `2023-01-24 06:00:00`

Just I want to remove `T` character between date and time and remove `.000Z` at the end.

Comment: Have you looked at libraries like luxon, dayjs etc

Comment: so reg exp replace text

Comment: epascarello can you show me how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the date in ISO 8601 format, you can use the 'sv' (Sweden) locale and [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

You can also specify whichever IANA timezone you wish to use, I'm using `UTC` in this case.

```js
const d = '2023-01-24T06:00:00.000Z'

let timestamp = new Date(d).toLocaleString('sv', { timeZone: 'UTC' });
console.log('Timestamp:', timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it is probably:

```
new Date(dataAPI.dateStation).toLocaleString()
```

If what you want is to display it somewhere, it'll automatically adapt the ISO date you have into a localized and readable date (based on timezone and language).

To know more about it and the options, here is the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: That gets you wildly different strings based on locale settings; here I get `m/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a/p`. Your best bet is probably `toLocaleString("sv")`, which gets you ISO8601 with space instead of T and no time zone field, but it will still be in local time, not UTC.

Comment: Yes indeed. The Sweden locale is closer to the question requirement, but I wanted to point out that it can easily be localized

Answer (score 1):

Use the javascript date class with toLocaleString

```
new Date(dataAPI.dateStation).toLocaleString('en-US');
```

Answer (score 1):

Without installing some third-party library, your best bet is probably to use the string you have (which is the format returned by `toISOString()` ),and modify it as desired. If it's already a string in the format you gave, you can just call `replace` on it:

```
dataAPI.dateStation.replace('T',' ').replace('.00Z','')
```

If it's a Date object, first call `toISOString()` to get a string:

```
dataAPI.dateStation.toISOString().replace('T',' ').replace('.00Z','')
```

If it's a string in a possibly-different format, call `new Date()` to get a Date object, then call `toISOString()` on that, and finally call `replace` on the result:

```
new Date(dataAPI.dateStation).toISOString().replace('T',' ').replace('.00Z','')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to remove the parts you don't want:

```js
let s = "2023-01-24T06:00:00.000Z"
s = s.replace(/T/, ' ')
s = s.replace(/\.\d{3}Z$/, '')
console.log(s)
```